# Can you sniff broadband connections? And how you secure that?

Tags: network, sniffer

I know that you can sniff data which is transferred over wifi. Can you do that with broadband (wired)? 
And how can you secure the network, so nobody could sniff data both over wifi, and broadband?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the broadband technology being used.  Generally, for most residential fiber and cable systems, about 32 or so houses share the same passive distribution network.  As such, the information coming from the ISP goes to all 32 customers and the cable modem filters down the information for each customer.  Using a hacked cable modem, it is possible to monitor all the traffic coming from the ISP, but it may or may not be encrypted depending on how the ISP is configured.

Similarly, traffic going to the ISP is moving in the wrong direction and can't be easily detected by other customers.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I secure my router, so no one could sniff other people requests?

Comment: And by broadband I meant that people use the same router at home. Can then data be sniffed?

Comment: @evening - you lost me now.  If you are asking about people on a wired network within the home network, a good switching based router should isolate each system and only pass along information that needs to go to each IP internally.  As long as it isn't going through any hubs (which send to all connections) you should be fine internally.

Comment: Thanks. I know that when using wifi, packets can be sniffed very easily, I was just wondering if that's possible with wired connection.

Comment: If your home router has a switch built in (as most do) then people on port 1 cannot directly read the traffic bound for port 2. That doesn't mean a clever person couldn't do all sorts of tricks to make it possible, but you know your housemates better than we do.

Comment: And what about securing wifi, so it couldn't be sniffed? Probably it's not possible, but maybe it's possible to use encryption or something in the router website, so even if packets are sniffed, you couldn't decrypt them?

Comment: @evening - you can make it so that wifi uses different encryption per connection, but this requires user level accounts for connecting to the wireless and the use of the enterprise levels of WPA or similar.  It is also non-trivial to setup.  With a common password, anyone with access to the network will be able to get at the contents of everyone else (on the wireless network)'s packets as they go across the wireless network.

Comment: @AJ Henderson: So, that just means I have to use VPN... There is no other easy way around, isn't? **edit:** or use wired instead of wifi.

Comment: @evening - it is probably your easiest bet for a wireless connection if you don't trust the other people on the wireless network, but at that point it brings up the question, why are they on your wireless network.

Comment: Or wired connection, right?

Comment: wired would be fine as long as the network is switched, which pretty much all are now.  You would have to look at the documentation for the routers and switches that are used in the network to see if it is switched or not, but most are now.

Comment: @AJHenderson: One more... What about setting Wireless Authentication and Wireless Encryption?

Comment: @evening - wireless encryption I already answered.  Encryption won't protect you from other people who are legitimately on the network unless you use enterprise level encryption (which is hard to setup) and authentication just establishes that people should be able to be on the network.

Comment: A wired network also isn't very secure, unless it is using enterprise grade hardware with filtering functions. [ARP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) is one way to sniff a local wired network.

Comment: @Josef - that's an excellent point, although isn't this what triggers the notification in Windows that multiple computers are using the same IP?  I never dug in to it more, but I know that in a situation where this happens as a legitimate failure (DHCP routing gets reset and legitimately assigns two computers the same IP address) then a notification rapidly appears.  I thought this was due to the system seeing an ARP response for it's own IP.  I guess there may still be a small vector for tainting prior to the target connecting until the ARP cache clears.

Comment: Or is it that they are arp spoofing the gateway?  I guess that one would be a bit harder to detect since the clients wouldn't be able to tell which is legitimate and which is not, however would this work since most routers are going to have the gateway on the WAN port and know to send the traffic there?  I guess milage may vary based on how well designed the router is though.